# How to add object to JSONArray

Tags: java, json, object, arraylist, arrayobject

I want to add an object to an array. If the data of `other_amount` is more than zero I want to add one object more. If it's equal to zero, it should add nothing. This is my code:

```
JSONArray acc_data = new JSONArray();
Map<String, Object> myaccount = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < mpay.size(); i++) {
    if(other_amount>0){
        myaccount.put("poAccount", other_account);
        myaccount.put("poAmount", other_amount);
        system.out.println(myaccount);
        //{poAccount=050017, poAmount=12}
    }

    myaccount.put("poAccount", amount_account);
    myaccount.put("poAmount", amount);
    system.out.println(myaccount);
    //{"poAccount":"050016","poAmount":"800"}

    acc_data.add(myaccount);
    system.out.println(acc_data);
    //[{"poAccount":"050016","poAmount":"800"}]
}
```

But I need it like this:

```
//[{"poAccount":"050016","poAmount":"800"},{poAccount=050017, poAmount=12}]
```

please help me to resolve it.

Comment: It seems like you want one key (e.g., `poAccount`) to map to two different values (e.g., `050016` and `050017`). This isn't possible with a `Map<String, Object>`, you'll probably want `Map<String, List<Object>>`

Comment: **{poAccount=050017, poAmount=12}** this is not a valid JSON format

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use map for your case. 
When your put the pair with existing in map key, the pair will be overwrited.
For example

```
map.put ("k1","v1");
```

Map contains one pair "k1":"v1"
The next call

```
map.put ("k1","newV1");
```

The first pair will be overwrited and map still contains 1 pair: "k1":"newV1"

For your case it's better to define simple POJO class with 2 fields `poAccount` and `poAmount`. And add them to the JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are following, it will not serve your requirement. You should use pojo to store the records and then populate the Json Array. You can have a look at this code and modify as per your requirements.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Mypojo mypojo = new Mypojo();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JSONArray records = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        if (5 > 0) {
            mypojo.setPoAccount("050017");
            mypojo.setPoAmount("12");
            JSONObject objects = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(mypojo));
            records.put(objects);
        }

        mypojo.setPoAccount("050016");
        mypojo.setPoAmount("800");
        JSONObject objects = new JSONObject(gson.toJson(mypojo));
        records.put(objects);
    }

    System.out.println(records);

}

}
```

Mypojo Class :

```
public class Mypojo
{
private String poAmount;

private String poAccount;

public String getPoAmount ()
{
    return poAmount;
}

public void setPoAmount (String poAmount)
{
    this.poAmount = poAmount;
}

public String getPoAccount ()
{
    return poAccount;
}

public void setPoAccount (String poAccount)
{
    this.poAccount = poAccount;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [poAmount = "+poAmount+", poAccount = "+poAccount+"]";
}
}
```